# Taking input from form, retrieving data from database and showing output

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, express

Im working with nodejs ,express and mongodb.And im working on cloud9 IDE

I want to create a page with a form which takes input from the user, search corresponding data from database and show that data on same page (after reloading) ,and if data isnt present then showing an specific response.

this is what i have done-

Route-

```
app.get("/",function(req,res){
var asked = req.query.asked;
  Name.findOne({name:asked},function(err,foundAsked){
      if(err){console.log("ERROR!!!");}
      else{res.render("Landing.ejs",{foundAsked:foundAsked}); }
  });
 });
```

EJS file-

```
//Form takes name as input from the user

<form >
    <input type="text" name="asked" action="/" method="GET">
    <button class="button">Submit</button>
</form>



//If data is found last name is returned
<% if(foundAsked){ %>
    <h2 >  <%= foundAsked.Lastname %> </h2>
<% } %>


 //blank space stays there which is replaced by a response,if after 
   //submission nothing is found
<% if(!foundAsked){ %>
    <h5></h5> 
<% } %>
```

JS-

```
 $(".button").click(function(){

          $("h5").text("No data present");
 });
```

But the problem is that,if there is no data found ,the response is shown ,but it stays for only the time before the page reloads.
I tried searching for an answer but i havnt found any.Please help

Comment: how does the full URL (including params) look like?

Comment: When you do `console.log(foundAsked)` what do you get in the console?

Comment: Its my main page,so the URL is simply "/",I edited that in the question too.@ShimonBrandsdorfer

Comment: does the `url` change by reloading?

Comment: I get- { _id: something,
  name: 'abc',
  Lastname: 'xyz'} @ShimonBrandsdorfer

Comment: Ok, but what do you get when no data found?

Comment: After submission of data URL changes to "/?asked=entereddata" @ShimonBrandsdorfer

Comment: I get - null ,if no data is found @ShimonBrandsdorfer

Comment: And how do you handle for request without any parameters?

Comment: Im sorry but i didnt get your question,foundAsked remains undefined when the page loads,once user enters the data, page is reloaded showing data (if found) or if not found,the blank text is replaced by the response ,this is the working @ShimonBrandsdorfer

Comment: Okay, forget it.
 what do you expect to happen after reloading? do you expect to see`"No data present"` ?

Comment: Yes that is what i want,and it is being displayed ,but only for time between the page reload and clicking on submission button @ShimonBrandsdorfer

Comment: Got you. let me post an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text you want to be shown, will appear only after the `button` is clicked, and once reloaded, you will have to click again (and the click will show the text, and trigger a reload, so the text will disappear again).

You need to have another button (That will not submit) to trigger this message. Or rather why not show initially (put this inline, inside the `<h5>` tags) ?

You need to differentiate between 'no-data' or 'no-query.
you can do it in the back-end, something similar to this:

```
app.get("/",function(req,res){
var asked = req.query.asked;
  Name.findOne({name:asked},function(err,foundAsked){
      if(err){console.log("ERROR!!!");}
      else{res.render("Landing.ejs",{foundAsked:foundAsked, asked: asked}); }
  });
 });
```

And then in `Landing.ejs`:

```
<% if(!foundAsked && asked){ %>
        <h5>No data present</h5> 
  <% } %>
```

Comment: But ,since the foundAsked is undefined initially (before the submission of form),it will show the response without  taking the input itself.I want to show it ,if foundAsked is undefined ,even after the form submission.

Comment: Thank you very much,worked very smoothly as i wanted.Thanks once again :)